# Removing everything in a column after a specific embeded character in a csv file

Tags: sed, regular-expression, perl, csv

I need to remove all the contents that appear in a column after a specific character in CSV file. 
This is the format it is currently in:

```
2020-01-01T12:00:00,Transaction Description,Initiator,$00.00
```

I want to remove the contents in the first column that appear after T, so that it looks like:

```
2020-01-01,Transaction Description,Initiator,$00.00
```

I tried sed but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using standard `sed` in a similar way as [Timur uses Perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577811/116858):

```
$ sed 's/T[^,]*//' file
2020-01-01,Transaction Description,Initiator,$00.00
```

This removes all text from the first `T` on each line, up to (but not including) the first comma, by means of a substitution.

Redirect to a new file to save the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's{T[^,]*}{}' input_file > output_file
```

Here,
`-e` command line flag tells Perl to use the code that follows in-line, rather than look for code in the specified script,
`-p` tells Perl to loop over input one line at a time, printing it after the specified code in executed,
`s{T[^,]*}{}` replaces `T` followed by any characters other than `,` zero or more times (`*` specifies greedy, or longest, match). This "eats up" the characters starting with the first T, inclusive, and ending with the first following comma, exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Method1:

```
awk -F "," 'OFS=","{gsub(/T.*/,"",$1);print $0}' filename
```

output

```
2020-01-01,Transaction Description,Initiator,$00.00
```

command2

```
perl -pne "s/,/\n/g" filenmame| sed '/.T/s/T.*//g'|perl -pne "s/\n/,/g"| sed "s/,$//g"
```

output

```
2020-01-01,Transaction Description,Initiator,$00.00
```

method3

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
p=re.compile(r'T.*')
k=open('p.txt','r')
for i in k:
    l=i.split(",")
    z=re.sub(p,"",l[0])
    rt=",".join(l[1:])
    er=",{0}".format(rt)
    print z+er,
```

output

```
2020-01-01,Transaction Description,Initiator,$00.00
```

Comment: `awk -F "," 'OFS=","{gsub(/T.*/,"",$1);print $0}' filename` makes no sense and I highly doubt that `perl | sed | perl | sed` is ever a reasonable solution to any problem.